# Is there a way to exclude parameters being autocompleted in IntelliSense?

Tags: python, parameters, autocomplete, intellisense

Is there a way to exclude parameters being autocompleted in IntelliSense?

I have used IntelliJ before, and I recently switched over to VS Code. Upon switching and installing IntelliSense, I have had issues with some of the autocompletes. For example, on tab completion of the print function, I would just expect it to complete as:

print()

but it instead completes as:

print(sep=..., end=..., file=..., flush=...)

Only for some functions does the autocomplete include the parameter suggestions, and not for other, and I cant seem to figure out why. I tried looking through the settings but without much luck. Any help?